# Heroku Dyno Requirements for a rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, hosting

Assume i have the following statistics relating to my Rails app.. (i pulled these numbers out of thin air).

```
pL = page load time (ms): 250 #total page load time from start to finish    
U = Users Online: 10
ULT = User Idle Time(s): 5  
R = Req Per Page: 5 #this includes js/css/html/images etc for each page, for sanity lets say caching is off.
```

would it be safe to assume that my application would require a single web dyno from Heroku? How might i calculate this as the number of users online scales up?

I currently have a seperate worker dyno dedicated to backend tasks such as sending emails, and other crap.

I used the formula..

```
1000/250 = 4 requests per second
```

but how do you correlate that to req per page and alloted users online?